# Error with blocks in a tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

```
\begin{figure}[H] \centering 
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1cm, auto] 
\node [block] (cipher) {Cifertekst}; 
\node [block,above left=of cipher,label={left:A}] (plaininput) {Klartekst}; 
\node [block,above right=of cipher] (encrypt) {Kryptering}; 
\node [block,below left=of cipher] (decrypt) {Dekryptering}; 
\node [block,below right=of cipher,label={right:B}] (plainoutput) {Klartekst};

    \draw[->] (plaininput) -- (encrypt);
    \draw[->] (encrypt) |- (cipher);
    \draw[->] (cipher) -| (decrypt);
    \draw[->] (decrypt) -- (plainoutput);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Grundlæggende kryptering}
\label{fig:grundlæggende kryptering}
\end{figure}
```

Somehow i seem to get this error when compiling: "I do not know the key '/tikz/block'

Comment: Welcome! Please don't post pictures of code but include the code in a code block. I've copied your code back into the question. If you could complete it so that people can copy-paste-compile it, that would be most useful. (Or copy-paste-attempt-to-compile it and get the error you are reporting.)

Comment: You have not defined any style `block` and it is not a default style. Either there is a library you need to add or this is something you need to create. However, it is hard to say how to correct it without knowing what you expect `block` to do. Nodes are all rectangles by default, so you don't need anything to achieve that. You might want to try `draw`, for example, to draw the borders of them?

Answer (score 4):

Do you want something like this?

[image: blocks]

I added a style

```
block/.style={draw}
```

to achieve this. Here's the complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1cm, auto, block/.style={draw}]
  \node [block] (cipher) {Cifertekst};
  \node [block, above left = of cipher, label = {left:A}] (plaininput) {Klartekst};
  \node [block, above right = of cipher] (encrypt) {Kryptering};
  \node [block, below left = of cipher] (decrypt) {Dekryptering};
  \node [block, below right = of cipher, label = {right:B}] (plainoutput) {Klartekst};

  \draw[->] (plaininput) -- (encrypt);
  \draw[->] (encrypt) |- (cipher);
  \draw[->] (cipher) -| (decrypt);
  \draw[->] (decrypt) -- (plainoutput);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```